# Replace all the div from row without moving other rows of a grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a grid of `div`'s. and those all `position:relative` inside its parent.
What I need to do is on click of one div, All the `div`s from that row will be hidden and that space will be occupied by first div with

```
width = number_of_div_in_one_row * orignal_width
```

ie whole row will be occupied by the div user clicked.
I tried lot many thinks. Calculated number of width in one row and Applied css animation for hiding each `div` and increasing width of first `div`.

but Whenever user clicks any `div`, all rows above it and below it are getting disturbed.
I am not asking anybody to do all calculation for me. Just want to ask is there any JS/jquery library that I can apply for this kind of scenarios. 
I already tried http://nanogallery.brisbois.fr/

But in this library all the images are replaced by other set of images. I just want to do something like this with only one row.

Comment: hide all other divs in that row except the clicked one and add the css method to give width to `100%` of the parent.

Comment: _is there any JS/jquery library_....????

Comment: yes. I did same thing. But it should happen in a soft flow. I mean with some animation. So When width of all other div start decreasing, those width goes to upper rows. As there is small space left.

Comment: sounds like you're looking for a sort of horizontal accordion effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand correctly your question but in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/w543X/1/) there is a fluid grid with three divs per row.
When you click on one div this gets 100% width and other divs in same rows disappear.
When you click on the div that has animated, the entire line will back to the starting point
all code you need is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.element').click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('go');
            if($(this).hasClass('go')){
                $(this).animate({'width':'100%'},{
                duration:1000,
                step:function(gox){
                  var width = gox < 100 ? (100 - gox) / 2 : 0;
                  $(this).siblings().css({
                      'border':'0px',
                      'width': width + "%"
                      }); 
                  }
                 })

            }else{
            $(this).parent('div.row').find('div.element').animate({'width':'33.33%'},1000);
        };
    });
});
</script>
```

If you have rows with differnt number of divs you culd do something like this:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/LnUqM/5/)
These are just simple examples, I hope them can help you.